# Moving keys towards 0 after they are removed

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

So I have an array:

```
Array ( [Favorite-Search-Engines] => Array ( 
[0] => Google 
[1] => Yahoo 
[2] => Bing 
[3] => DuckDuckGo ) )
```

I want the user to be able to remove a key, but if they remove one:

```
Array ( 
[Favorite-Search-Engines] => Array ( 
[0] => Google
[2] => Bing 
[3] => DuckDuckGo ) )
```

I would like the keys to move down towards 0 like this:

Array ( 
    [Favorite-Search-Engines] => Array ( 
    [0] => Google
    [1] => Bing 
    [2] => DuckDuckGo ) )

Is there any way to do this?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to to that is to use:

```
$re_indexed_array = array_values($your_modified_array);
```